# What is the different between phonegap and meteor

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, web

I want to start developing an android application with web technologies.

While looking on the internet i found phone-gap and meteor,
i wanted to ask what is the different between those?

If they are competing each other, which one should i use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

They aren't mutually exclusive, they're complimentary.  PhoneGap a product that allows you to write the majority of your native application code using HTML5, CSS, JavaScript and any choice of MVC or other JS framework that you would like to use.  Native functionality that can't normally be accessed in a browser or embedded web view is accessed via plugins, for which there are many available off the shelf.  PhoneGap is an Adobe product that has features such as PhoneGap Build, a SaaS service for building and packaging your native apps for distribution across a range of platforms.

Apache Cordova is the open source project that PhoneGap is based on, providing the same features more or less with the lack of the online SaaS platform.  You would build and distribute apps using Xcode or Android SDK tools on your local machine or build server, having written those apps using JS / CSS / HTML.

Meteor is a platform for building web applications with JavaScript, that works with many JS frameworks that you can also use with PhoneGap / Cordova, for example React JS or Angular.  Meteor is used when you want realtime server to client communications and has 3 way data binding.

If you want to build a native app using features of Meteor you can do that and go ahead and use Cordova or PhoneGap to wrap it and make it able to access device native features and leverage the App Store and Google Play as distribution points.

Useful resources:

- [Cordova website](https://cordova.apache.org/)
- [Meteor website](https://www.meteor.com/)